# How to create legend for D3 Sequence Sunburst?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm modifying the original D3 [Sequence Sunburst file](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426%20Sequence%20Sunburst) to better suit my needs. The original `colors` variable is a hard-coded object. This clearly cannot be the best method. I'm using the flare.json example, which is larger, harder to read, and still much smaller than the json file I will be user after testing.

I'd like to randomly generate colors, apply them to each datum in the `createvisualization` function, but I'm new to D3, and do not know how to 1) fetch names (everything but the leaves) from the json file, and 2) pair them with their random color.

#### Edit:

Adding random colors and applying them turned out to be trivial,

```
var colors = d3.scale.category10();
...
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return colors(i); })
```

But I'm still note sure how to fetch the names of all non-leaves in the json, then create an array from both the random colors and the non-leaves.

Help here greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the names of all non-leaf elements, you can do something like this.

```
var names = [];

function getNames(node) {
  if(node.children) {
    names.push(node.name);
    node.children.forEach(function(c) { getNames(c); });
  }
}

getNames(root);
```

After running this code, `names` will contain all the names you want. To then generate a legend from that, you can use the `names` array as the data:

```
var gs = svg.selectAll("g.name").data(names).enter().append("g").attr("class", "name");
gs.append("rect")
  // set position, size etc
  .attr("fill", d);
gs.append("text")
  // set position etc
  .text(String);
```

This will append a `g` element for each name and within each `g` element, append a `rect` that is filled with the colour corresponding to the name and a `text` element that shows the name.

Comment: Two comments. First, I wasn't able to get the desired functionality from these code snippets, but I got closer to where I wanted, and it probably didn't work 100% because I'm a newb. As such, I'm giving you the green check.

That said, with a large number of categories, I'm thinking that a traditional legend is undesirable - it's just ugly on screen. Do you have any suggestions for a key to a large sequence diagram?

Comment: Well, it would have helped if you had posted the code and data you were actually using for this -- I tried to extrapolate from the example you've linked to, but obviously I can only guess what you're actually doing. For a large number of categories, I probably would do away with the legend completely and show the key on mouseover or something like that.

Comment: I'll put my stuff in a fiddle next time. For now, I think you are right though - hovers are the way to go. The d3 demo I linked to already have these hovers, and they're quite nice.