# How to add legends to a sunburst chart in nvd3?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Is there a way to add legends to a sunburst NVD3 chart? I'm doing this and it's currently not working.

```
chart = nv.models.sunburstChart()          
      .showTooltipPercent(true)
      .color(d3.scale.category20c())
      .showLabels(false)
      .margin({bottom: 20, top: 10,right:0})
      .showLegend(true)
      .mode("value")
```

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502187/how-to-create-legend-for-d3-sequence-sunburst)?

Comment: @shabeer90 yes. But here i'm not using that code. Here i'm using the sunburst chart from nvd3 libray.